# Java - identify system calls associated with method calls

Tags: java, system-calls, strace

I'm trying to identify what system calls are made by my java program when it runs. Even more specifically, I want to know what java methods invoke what system calls. I've tried strace in Linux:

```
strace -o output.txt java MyProgram
```

This, however, outputs every system call my program makes into output.txt, and is not specific to each method.
Thanks.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Its a part of my Operating Systems class assignment, so there really is no reason ;)

Comment: Read the OpenJDK source?

Comment: I think you would need to use a profiling program to do what you are asking. JetBrains has some nice software: http://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#java

Comment: I too interested to know the system call made by java native method. I wanted to see which system call used for name resolution. Above command didnot map to any system call. And return strace like below:
```
[root@sdl21ntf-cluster-4-0-ntf-vm0 ~]# strace -p 4516
strace: Process 4516 attached
futex(0x7f7e6f1369d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 4517, NULL) = 0
munmap(0x7f7e5f0b6000, 141534522)       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 ++
```